# Firebase Analytics user lifetime values

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

I used Firebase analytics with my newest iOS app and I am wondering how I can find user lifetime values in the console. I am particularly interested in number of sessions and the total lifetime session length. This is all available in Google Analytics but I seem not be able to figure out how to get this in Firebase Analytics. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Analytics only provides lifetime value for in-app purchases and eCommerce purchases. It doesn't automatically record lifetime session count or lifetime user engagement. You could possibly build this using BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Analytics Console doesn't have this feature out of the box but if you enable the Firebase BigQuery Integration, you will have access to these metrics in raw format.

We have the session length, and lifetime value metrics defined as SQL expressions, you can take a look at them [from here](https://rakam.io/solution/firebase).